# django-puppeteer-pdf static files

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, puppeteer

I'm having django-puppeteer-pdf installed on my project. Page loads with css and PDF generation works great. But css files on STATIC_ROOT does not work on pdf. Any idea how to get this work?

In html template I'm having static files loaded:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/pdf-reports.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

and settings.py file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_files")
```